# How to uncheck checkbox using jQuery Uniform library

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a problem with unchecking a `checkbox`. Have a look at [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r87NH/), where I am attempting:

```
   $("#check2").attr("checked", true);
```

I use [uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/#example) for styling the `checkbox` and it simply does not work to **check/uncheck** the `checkbox`.

Any ideas?

Comment: both in google chrome and firefox it does not work for me

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Looking at their docs, they have a `$.uniform.update` feature to refresh a "uniformed" element.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/r87NH/4/

```
$("input:checkbox").uniform();

$("body").on("click", "#check1", function () {
    var two = $("#check2").attr("checked", this.checked);
    $.uniform.update(two);
});
```

Comment: @mkoryak: Works fine in `1.4.4`, but the links to the js and css files were broken. [Here's an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r87NH/106/) If you mean that it'll have issues specifically in `1.6`, then that's probably true since jQuery changed then reverted behavior of `.attr()`. Using `1.6` or higher, you should really be using `.prop()`.

Comment: I can see absolutely no difference at all between the updated jsFiddle and the original (right down to the mislabeling of checkbox 2), except the updated version works for me and the original didn't!?!?

Comment: BTW all these pixel-drawn Uniform forms look very *unsexy* on Retina.

Comment: did not work for me also jsfiddle does not work or is confusing

Answer (score 368):

A simpler solution is to do this rather than using uniform:

```
$('#check1').prop('checked', true); // will check the checkbox with id check1
$('#check1').prop('checked', false); // will uncheck the checkbox with id check1
```

This will not trigger any click action defined.

You can also use:

```
$('#check1').click(); //
```

This will toggle the check/uncheck for the checkbox but this will also trigger any click action you have defined. So be careful.

**EDIT**: jQuery 1.6+ uses `prop()` not `attr()` for checkboxes checked value

Comment: This leaves the checked attribute as-is in jQuery 1.7.1 for me. Works but doesn't do what you think it should.

Answer (score 24):

```
$("#chkBox").attr('checked', false);
```

This worked for me, this will uncheck the check box.
In the same way we can use

```
$("#chkBox").attr('checked', true);
```

to check the checkbox.

Comment: I think it's better to use the .prop() function instead of .attr(). Otherwise it won't work always as expected ...

Answer (score 13):

If you are using [uniform 1.5](http://uniformjs.com) then use this simple trick to add or remove attribute of check
 Just add value="check" in your checkbox's input field.
 Add this code in `uniform.js` > `function doCheckbox(elem){` > `.click(function(){`

```
if ( $(elem+':checked').val() == 'check' ) {
    $(elem).attr('checked','checked');           
}
else {
    $(elem).removeAttr('checked');
}
```

if you not want to add value="check" in your input box because in some cases you add two checkboxes so use this

```
if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {
 $(elem).attr('checked','checked');
}    
else
{    
 $(elem).removeAttr('checked');
}
```

If you are using [uniform 2.0](http://uniformjs.com) then use this simple trick to add or remove attribute of check
 in this `classUpdateChecked($tag, $el, options) {` function change

```
if ($el.prop) {
    // jQuery 1.6+
    $el.prop(c, isChecked);
}
```

To

```
if ($el.prop) {
    // jQuery 1.6+
    $el.prop(c, isChecked);
    if (isChecked) {
        $el.attr(c, c);
    } else {
        $el.removeAttr(c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#check1').prop('checked', true).uniform(); 
$('#check1').prop('checked', false).uniform();
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can confirm that this is the most simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true).uniform('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `$.uniform.update()` if you update element using javascript as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `checked` can have a value of `checked`, or an empty string.

```
$("input:checkbox").uniform();

$('#check1').live('click', function() {
    $('#check2').attr('checked', 'checked').uniform();
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing a boolean as the value of `checked`.

Comment: But we're not writing HTML markup. We're setting a property on the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement). Have a look at the `checked` property.

Comment: Never mind… I don't really understand why it's invalid, either…

Comment: passing a boolean value is only supported in 1.6+, before that you had to set the checked attribute to 'checked' or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

In some case you can use this:

```
$('.myInput').get(0).checked = true
```

For toggle you can use if else with function

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $("#checkall").change(function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (checked) {
                $(".custom-checkbox").each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true).uniform();
                });
            } else {
                $(".custom-checkbox").each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false).uniform();
                });
            }
        });

        // Changing state of CheckAll custom-checkbox
        $(".custom-checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(".custom-checkbox").length == $(".custom-checkbox:checked").length) {
                $("#chk-all").prop("checked", true).uniform();
            } else {
                $("#chk-all").removeAttr("checked").uniform();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id='checkall' /> Select All<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" class='custom-checkbox' name="languages" value="PHP"> PHP<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" class='custom-checkbox' name="languages" value="AngularJS"> AngularJS<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" class='custom-checkbox' name="languages" value="Python"> Python<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" class='custom-checkbox' name="languages" value="Java"> Java<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do is is,

use `$('#check2').click();`

this causes uniform to check the checkbox and update it's masks

Answer (score -1):

checkbox that act like radio btn

`$(".checkgroup").live('change',function() {
    var previous=this.checked;
    $(".checkgroup).attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked", previous);
});`